# Cast SelectedItem to Object C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, casting, windows-phone

I have a list of images and their respective links. Everything loaded on my page working, but need to get the link of the page that are in the repository "Tag" each textBlock in my listbox. See the code below to understand better.

```
<TextBlock Tag="{Binding Path=Url}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Titulo}" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF159DDE" TextWrapping="Wrap" /> //Works Fine
```

In the SelectionChanged method I need to grab this URL in this tag making a cast for each selection he seek the url for the selected textblock.

My code is this so far, but he is finding a property null object:

```
 private void listBoxPopular_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int aux = 0;
        var app = (Application.Current as App);

        TextBlock txt = listBoxPopular.SelectedItem as TextBlock;            
        if (txt != null)
              app.URI = (txt.Tag ?? String.Empty).ToString();     //app.URI is a global string
        ApplicationBarra(aux);
        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual type returned by listBoxPopular.SelectedItem?

e.g. listBoxPopular.SelectedItem.GetType()

Comment: @codemonkeh I am beginner and do not know what to do to answer your question correctly. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedItem` is not of type `TextBlock`, but of the type of the items in the List's `ItemsSource`, this is the type which holds the `Url` and `Titulo` properties.

```
private void listBoxPopular_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int aux = 0;
    var app = (Application.Current as App);

    var selectedViewModel = listBoxPopular.SelectedItem as PopularVideos; 

    if (selectedViewModel != null)
          app.URI = selectedViewModel.Url ?? String.Empty;     

    ApplicationBarra(aux);
    ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
}
```

I would suggest checking `SelectedItem` for null before using it. You can use the EventArgs instead of `listBoxPopular` and make the method static. Basically a matter of style, though..

Comment: I think it will work, but I have an error in XYViewModel this class does not exist.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, need to change that class XYViewModel to the class that works with the listbox in my case was the PopularVideos. I made this change and it worked perfectly. Thank you! Edit your post to stay for the next people and everything right!

var selectedViewModel = listBoxPopular.SelectedItem as PopularVideos;